# Circle geometry and plotting in color with Shapely

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, gis, shapely

I am trying to draw a bunch of overlapping circles using Shapely in Python. I can choose the centers of the circles and the radii, but I am having trouble determining where the centers *should* be to make a flower of life design.

I found this [super cool tutorial](https://medium.com/@brokyo/drawing-the-flower-of-life-22206fe36d02), but I have no experience with Javascript and figure it shouldn't be too hard to do in Python. I hope there is a geometry Python nerd out there who can help me!

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiPolygon
from shapely.ops import unary_union
from math import sqrt, floor, pi, cos, sin, acos, asin

# two functions for plotting
def plot_coords(coords):
    pts = list(coords)
    x, y = zip(*pts)
    plt.plot(x,y)

def plot_polys(polys):
    for poly in polys:
        plot_coords(poly.exterior.coords)
        plt.fill_between(*poly.exterior.xy, alpha=.5)

# buffer points to make circles
circles = []
x = 100
y = 100
center = Point(x,y)
radius = 10

circle1 = circles.append(center.buffer(radius))

# if you want to view the one circle:
plot_polys(circles)
plt.show()
```

If the second circle is at a 60º angle from the center of the first, I should be able to plot them like so (desperately need help with a loop here):

```
center2 = Point(x + radius * cos(60), y + radius * sin(60))
circles.append(center2.buffer(radius))

center3 = Point(x + radius * cos(60*2), y + radius * sin(60*2))
circles.append(center3.buffer(radius))

center4 = Point(x + radius * cos(60*3), y + radius * sin(60*3))
circles.append(center4.buffer(radius))

center5 = Point(x + radius * cos(60*4), y + radius * sin(60*4))
circles.append(center5.buffer(radius))

center6 = Point(x + radius * cos(60*5), y + radius * sin(60*5))
circles.append(center6.buffer(radius))

plot_polys(circles)

plt.xlim([50,150])
plt.ylim([50,150])
plt.show()
```

Yields:

[image]

So, this is obviously wrong. Is this a radians/degrees thing? From what I've read, I think Shapely would default to degrees?

I want to produce a plot that looks like the flower of life. These first 6 circles should be the first ring, but they're not in the right places. In addition to fixing this, I also need to think about how to calculate the next ring of circles.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kinda misleading, because it seems the main problem you have is that you missed that the trigonometric functions from `math` work with radians rather than degrees, so it doesn't really relate to `shapely` per se.

You can use `math.radians(x)` to convert from degrees to radians, and then use `cos` and `sin` functions.

Other than that I think you miss one circle for the first ring. There should be 6 surrounding 1, i.e. 7 in total.

And I think I would just calculate the cosine of 30 degrees once, with that you could already derive all 6 positions (i.e. two on the vertical line going through the original center, and the other four are 30 degrees away from the horizontal line going through the original center, just in different directions).

For every further outer ring you simply add / substract the same numbers in an iterative / recursive approach.